# are there any ASP.NET embedded Service Bus application?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, servicebus

I have a site that is hosted in a shared hosting environment. To that site I can open sub-sites using sub domains.

I have the need to use sort of a message queue service bus - when my ASP.NET website can put tasks, and a home computer (yes - a home computer is fine for now) can ask for a waiting task and perform some operation offline for the website.

Since the shared hosting doesn't support MSMQ, RABITMQ or any technology that's out of the scope of a shared hosting (due to clients budget it has to stay on shared hosting - I would have moved it if I could), I was wondering if anyone knows about some sort of an embedded  service bus that I could install on a sub domain of the site and add tasks to it, and later an offline console application will get tasks from that bus.

does such thing exists or am I asking for too much?

Thanks

Comment: There are no such things as embedded service bus applications inside ASP.NET. Besides it would have been a terribly bad idea to implement anything like that inside a web application: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/ The only reliable way to do this is to put it inside some other service (such as a Windows service for example). If you don't want a full blown messaging system, a simple in-memory (not resilient of course) `ConcurrentQueue<T>` could do the job just fine.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov thanks for answering. But in memory could be problematic since if the app pool recycles then I will lose all tasks. I need something simple that would be able to save tasks and retrieve them later (of course once a task is retrieved, it's locked for other retrievals)

Comment: But who is talking about AppPools? Did you read my comment? Such things shouldn't be hosted inside ASP.NET applications. You should have a separate service (such as a Windows Service) for this task. One of the reasons is precisely because the AppPool can recycle at any time (out of your control) and you will lose everything. So I am afraid that you cannot achieve anything reliable if you cannot use a real messaging system or at least have the possibility of implementing one yourself in a separate container of course.

Comment: I don't see a reason why such thing shouldn't exist. Basically, something that saves messages and something that knows how to smartly retrieve them.

Comment: You mean something that will persist the messages somewhere? Yes, this makes sense then. I am not aware of such implementation though. That's probably because people simply use the tools that are designed for this purpose: MSMQ, RabbitMQ, ...

Comment: yes. it could save the message inside SQL Server, My-SQL, some embedded no-sql (such as RavenDb). The important thing is something that I could call and will know to hand me back tasks from the database.

Comment: @developer82 Would you mind telling me which embedded service bus you used? I have the same need.

Comment: @grokky I used cloudamqp

Comment: @developer82 Thanks. So I assume you couldn't find an embedded one. :-(

Comment: @grokky Sadly no. The best you can do is use the .NET queue class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue(v=vs.110).aspx). You can wrap it in your own code if you need the queue to be persistent.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure Service Bus is a Messaging service available thru a PAAS offering, so you can consume the APIs from your ASP.NET application that is hosted anywhere (private cloud, public clouds etc. ). The functionality can be accessed from any process (web service etc.) but it is unclear how a web app will be able to wait for messages, it will need something to wake it up to check for a available message?

The below sample shows how you can send messages to Service Bus Queues using ASP.NET web app: 
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Multi-Tier-application-6c033cad

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer - but that wasn't what I was aiming at. I know the azure service bus and have used it in another service. What I need is my own hostable service bus - I was thinking in a form of maybe a WCF service.